# my select query removing duplicate row

Tags: mysql, sql

I created this select query to get some rows... Its working. but my problem is I need to remove duplicate rows from the query...

this is my query:

```
SELECT tcs.tutor_id, tcs.category_id, tcs.subject_id, s.subjects, t.tutor_name, t.tutor_code
FROM tutor_category_subject as tcs
INNER JOIN subject AS s ON tcs.subject_id = s.subject_id
INNER JOIN tutors AS t ON tcs.tutor_id = t.tutor_id
WHERE s.subjects LIKE '%business%';
```

This is its output:

```
    +----------+-------------+------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------+ 

| tutor_id | category_id | subject_id | subjects         | tutor_name        | tutor_code|

+----------+-------------+------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------+

|        1 |           6 |         37 | Business Studies | Tharanga Nuwan    |      1250 |
|        3 |           6 |         37 | Business Studies | Kumara            |      1252 | 
|       15 |           4 |         11 | Business & Accou | Tharanga Nuwan    |      1264 | 
|       15 |           6 |         37 | Business Studies | Tharanga Nuwan    |      1264 |
|       16 |           5 |         11 | Business & Accou | Kasun Kalhara     |      1265 | 
|       16 |           6 |         37 | Business Studies | Kasun Kalhara     |      1265 |
```

Here, you can see tutor id has duplicated in my query. and I need to select all subjects to a tutor in one row separated by comma.

eg: (Business & Accounting Studies, Business Studies) like this..

So can anybody tell me what I need to do in my select query??

Thank you.

This is my expecting result

```
+----------+-------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+------------+
| tutor_id | category_id | subject_id | subjects                                        | tutor_name            | tutor_code |
+----------+-------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+------------+
|       16 |           5 |         11 | Business & Accounting Studies, Business Studies | Kasun Kalhara         |       1265 |
|        3 |           6 |         37 | Business Studies                                | Kumara                |       1252 |
|        1 |           6 |         37 | Business Studies, Business & Accounting Studies | Tharanga Nuwan Kumara |       1250 |
+----------+-------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT tcs.tutor_id, tcs.category_id, tcs.subject_id, GROUP_CONCAT(s.subjects) AS subjects,  t.tutor_name, t.tutor_code
FROM tutor_category_subject as tcs
INNER JOIN subject AS s ON tcs.subject_id = s.subject_id
INNER JOIN tutors AS t ON tcs.tutor_id = t.tutor_id
WHERE s.subjects LIKE '%business%'
GROUP BY t.tutor_name;
```

Comment: thanks.. but cant get all tutors.. In my original query select 4 tutors but this one select 3 tutors... but duplication have removed.

Comment: can you please post the formated desired results, or you can use `group by` for duplicate value column.

Comment: I added my expecting result into the question

Answer (score 2):

In order to have the subjects in one row, you should create a function that will return a comma seperated string with the subjects per tutor. Probably you will need to pass as a parameter the tutor_id (and probably also a string with the "like clause" you need to add). Then in your select you will have something like this:

```
SELECT tcs.tutor_id, tcs.category_id, t.tutor_name, t.tutor_code, function_name(tcs.tutor_id)
FROM tutor_category_subject as tcs
INNER JOIN tutors AS t ON tcs.tutor_id = t.tutor_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tcs.tutor_id, tcs.category_id, tcs.subject_id, s.subjects, t.tutor_name, t.tutor_code
FROM tutor_category_subject as tcs
INNER JOIN subject AS s ON tcs.subject_id = s.subject_id
INNER JOIN tutors AS t ON tcs.tutor_id = t.tutor_id
WHERE s.subjects LIKE '%business%';
```

or:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW tcs.tutor_id, tcs.category_id, tcs.subject_id, s.subjects, t.tutor_name, t.tutor_code
    FROM tutor_category_subject as tcs
    INNER JOIN subject AS s ON tcs.subject_id = s.subject_id
    INNER JOIN tutors AS t ON tcs.tutor_id = t.tutor_id
    WHERE s.subjects LIKE '%business%';
```

Comment: I tried with both query that you have given.. but the result is same.

Comment: can you just format your output so it becomes more readable, this is just a mess. maybe than I'll see the problem. will you?

Comment: I see. It Its lot cleaner now. did you find your solution jet? i see some answers?

Answer (score 0):

Try this now, distinct with group by:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tcs.tutor_id, tcs.category_id, tcs.subject_id, group_by(s.subjects), t.tutor_name, t.tutor_code
    FROM tutor_category_subject as tcs
    INNER JOIN subject AS s ON tcs.subject_id = s.subject_id
    INNER JOIN tutors AS t ON tcs.tutor_id = t.tutor_id
    WHERE s.subjects LIKE '%business%'
    GROUP BY tcs.tutor_id;
```